# slice a string by different characters using Python Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

how to slice a string in dataframe, start from left, based on different characters, such as '  /- . , I only want the first time this character shows up.

```
key   name
1   McDonald's
2   CVS/PHARMACY
3   CVS/Store
4   WAL-MART
5   AMAZON.CO
```

expect result:

```
key   name            for_Group
1   McDonald's        McDonald
2   CVS/PHARMACY         CVS
3   CVS/Store            CVS
4   WAL-MART             WAL
5   AMAZON.CO          AMAZON
```

I'm not sure if this need to use regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Option 1***
**`str.split`** with **`expand=True`**

```
df['for_group'] = df.name.str.split(r"[\'\/\-\.]", expand=True)[0]

   key          name for_group
0    1    McDonald's  McDonald
1    2  CVS/PHARMACY       CVS
2    3     CVS/Store       CVS
3    4      WAL-MART       WAL
4    5     AMAZON.CO    AMAZON
```

***Option 2*** (Best option)
**`str.extract`** (I personally prefer this one, it matches until it finds one of your desired stop characters)

```
df.name.str.extract(r'(.*?)[\'\/\-\.]', expand=False)

0    McDonald
1         CVS
2         CVS
3         WAL
4      AMAZON
```

The second option here is much faster:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit df.name.str.split(r"[\'\/\-\.]", expand=True)[0]
141 ms ± 1.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.name.str.extract(r'(.*)[\'\/\-\.]', expand=False)
72.6 ms ± 397 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Be careful with str.extract, I realized that its accuracy rate is bad, when I test it on 300k rows of dataset, In Contract, str.split is 100% accuracy.

Comment: @Learn I'm guessing you were using `(.*)[\'\/\-\.]` as the regex with `extract`.  I updated it to `(.*?)[\'\/\-\.]` which should fix bad matches.  I would recommend trying the current version in my answer and seeing if that works better for you!

Comment: after your update, both of them hit 100% accuracy, Bingo!

Comment: A bit of explanation, `(.*)[\'\/\-\.]` will match from the beginning of your string until the ***last*** delimiter, but you want lazy matching and by using `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` it only matches until the first occurence of a delimiter

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

You can use the below regular expression, which means a word character (a-z etc.) repeated one or more times. This returns an array and you can take the first element off it.

```
import re
df['for_group'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[\w]+", x)[0])
```

A faster approach to regular expression would be to use `.search()` as pointed out by @user3483203

```
df['for_group'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r"[\w]+", x).group())
```

**Method 2**

Similarly, you can use:

```
df['for_group'] = df.name.str.split('\W+').apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
    key          name for_group
0    1    McDonald's  McDonald
1    2  CVS/PHARMACY       CVS
2    3     CVS/Store       CVS
3    4      WAL-MART       WAL
4    5     AMAZON.CO    AMAZON
```

Comment: Your first method can be made considerably faster by using `search` as opposed to `findall`, so `df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r"[\w]+", x).group())`

Comment: @user3483203, you are absolutely right. For large dataframe, `.findall()` takes `73.8 ms ± 1.22 ms` time while `.search()` takes `60.1 ms ± 552 µs`. Thanks.

Comment: On this dataset, since there will only be a couple results it doesn't matter, but if there were many results it would skew even more.  Same reason extract is better than split in my answer.  It returns after a single match

Comment: @user3483203, oh I see. Then is it safe to say that if we had long sentences to split instead of couple word string, we are better off using `.split()` and/or `.findall()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  `search` and `extract` return after the first match is found, while `split` and `findall` will search the entire string.  If the strings in the columns were longer `search/extract` would be even more desireable.

Comment: @user3483203, I think I got it. May be I will get more knowledge as I play with these four functions on my own and `%timeit`. Thanks again.

Comment: @HarvIpan your method 2 has "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" error, but it works for a small sample dataset

Comment: @Learn, the code works fine with minimal example from your question. If you can find the data for which is throwing error, I may help.